# Tehnologies Needed for iPhone App and Site Interaction

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

I'm not a developer, so I don't know too much about coding/programming. But I am interested in getting it developed, and I'm in the process of gathering information on what technologies are needed to make the idea happen.

Basically, it's an app which contains a custom designed visual floor plan segmented into sections. Each section has information (list in the form of text and an icon) attached to it which is updated via the website frequently. The information for each section can only be modified by certain users on the website.

One of the screens on the app will be a list of this info from each section, but only the most recently updated. It will need the ability to customize the updates from each section i.e. filter which ones show up, and in what order.

The app will also need the ability to push these updates by notification. And also location capabilities, like the ability to provide directions on the customized visual map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For All these things you need technologies mentioned below.

1. Core Location for location services.
2. Web Services (Use ASIHTTPRequest Library).
3. Objective-C for code all things together.
4. A good logical Mind to develop the application.
5. MVC- Design Pattern.
6. Push Notification Service for notifications.
7. MKMapKit for your map purpose.

Comment: This is very helpful. Would you mind expaning on MVC, what does it stand for? Thanks a ton Rahul.

Comment: MVC is design pattern for the appslication/softwares. You need to learn it how to apply MVC Design Pattern + Object Oriented Concepts into your code.